# How to check if there is no input from keyboard or mouse for a period of time in C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to write a line of code that checks if there is no input from keyboard and mouse and no change in the mouse position over a period of one minute. If this condition is true then trigger an event:

```
if ((no_Keyboard_input) && (no_mouse_input) && (no_change_in_mousePosition))
{
    start_timer;
    if (time_elapsed == 1 min)
    {
         playAnimation;
    }
}
```

Comment: You forgot to tell what your question/problem is.

Comment: What library do you use? WinForms or WPF?

Answer (score 9):

Using API, Here is a method I used before:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool GetLastInputInfo(ref LASTINPUTINFO plii);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, ExactSpelling = true)]
public static extern int GetTickCount();

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct LASTINPUTINFO
{
    public static readonly int SizeOf = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(LASTINPUTINFO));

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
    public int cbSize;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
    public UInt32 dwTime;
}
```

How to use it:

```
public static TimeSpan GetIdleTime()
{
    TimeSpan idleTime = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(0);

    LASTINPUTINFO lastInputInfo = new LASTINPUTINFO();
    lastInputInfo.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(lastInputInfo);
    lastInputInfo.dwTime = 0;

    if (GetLastInputInfo(ref lastInputInfo))
    {
        idleTime = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(GetTickCount() - (lastInputInfo.dwTime & uint.MaxValue));
        //idleTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Convert.ToInt32(lastInputInfo.dwTime / 1000));
    }

    return idleTime;
}
```

**Edit:** Add `GetTickCount()` API Signature.

Comment: +1 (but I think you forgot to add the p/invoke signature for `GetTickCount()`). Also, I am not sure if truncating `dwTime` to `0xFFFFFFFF` is the best idea (I would rather do an `Int64` subtraction and then downcast). **(Edit)** Ok, actually there is no difference since `dwTime` is `UInt32` anyway, never mind.

Comment: @Ismael: did you try this? does this answers your question?

Answer (score 0):

I'd have a look at [Reactive Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609) for something like this. They provide a nice way of composing many different events into a single one, and the nice LINQ syntax to get it done.

The code below is untested, but an idea of how you might get it done this way.

```
DateTime lastKeyboardInput, lastMouseInput;

var mouse = Observable.FromEvent<MouseEventArgs>(MouseDown);
var keyboard = Observable.FromEvent<KeyPressEventArgs>(KeyPress);
var seconds = Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
mouse.Subscribe(m => lastMouseInput = DateTime.Now());
keyboard.Subscribe(k => lastKeyboardInput = DateTime.Now());

var myEvent = from tick in seconds
          where lastKeyboardEvent < DateTime.Now() - TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60)
          where lastMouseEvent < DateTime.Now() - TimeSpawn.FromSeconds(60)
          select tick;

myEvent.Subscribe(t => playAnimation());
```